# What is the sturcture of RW2 file?

Tags: file-format, tiff, raw

Can any one tell me that the Panasonic's **RW2**(RAW Format) is based on TIFF or not ?

The header is same as of old format (**RAW**).

Answer (score 1):

The File Formats wiki says this for
[Panasonic RAW/RW2](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/RW2):

> Panasonic RAW/RW2, also known as Leica RAW or RWL, is a raw image
>   format used by some Panasonic and Leica digital cameras. It can also
>   be known by a camera-specific name such as Lumix RAW or Panasonic LX3
>   RAW.
>
> Different cameras produce different versions of it, and at some point
>   the .raw file extension was changed to .rw2. The term Panasonic RAW
>   might refer to just the .raw files, but more likely includes both .raw
>   and .rw2.
>
> The format is TIFF-like, but with a different file signature, and some
>   different tag numbers.
>
> The Leica version of it contains a MakerNote that begins with "LEICA"
>   0x00 0x00 0x00.

So it is based on TIFF, with the addition of proprietary tag blocks that contain
proprietary data whose format is not in the TIFF specifications.
RW2 is an evolution of RAW, but for the exact documentation you will need
to contact Panasonic, as this is does not seem to be published.

Comment: i found the thumbnail using tags but i can't find its size so,can you tell me which tags will give its size.